# How do I show only a subset of options in a Django dropdown menu

Tags: django, subset, dropdown

I have an app that allows users to signup and register for courses (from a 'TrainingInstance' model). These events have names etc and are categorised as Past or Current in the database (in the 'Training' model). When I show the BuildOrderForm in my template, I want only options for Current trainings to be shown in the dropdown menu. How can this be done in Django without javascript or Ajax?

I have the following form in forms.py:

```
class BuildOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['training_registered']
```

And the following models in models.py:

```
class Training(models.Model):
    """ Model which specifies the training category (name) and whether they are Past or Present""" 
        YEAR = (
            ('current', 'current'),
            ('past', 'past'),
            )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        year= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=YEAR, default='current')
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class TrainingInstance(models.Model):
    """ Creates a model of different instances of each training ( May 2021 etc) """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    training = models.ForeignKey(Training, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True)
    
    training_month = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    participant_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    staff_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    graduation_date = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Order(models.Model):
    REGSTATUS = (
        ('registered', 'registered'),
        ('enrolled', 'enrolled'),
        ('holding', 'holding'),
        ('withdrawn', 'withdrawn'),
        ('waiting', 'waiting'),
        )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True)
    training_registered = models.ForeignKey(TrainingInstance, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    regstatus = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=REGSTATUS, default='registered')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.username
```

Comment: Do you mean you need a query to filter the `Order` instances?

Comment: Can you add your **Customer** class as well ? A solution to your problem would probably be in your `views.py`, so when a **Customer** request your page, you get his **Training** list, and then filter it and do some rendering on the template, next to your **BuildOrderForm**, and take all datas (with **cleaned_data**) to create an order.

Comment: Hi, I want a potential registrant to only see options for 'current' trainings. The 'Past' trainings are now finished and I don't want them appearing as options in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done - which works but I'm also open to feedback about good/bad practice.

```
class BuildOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['training_registered']
    
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super (BuildOrderForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['training_registered'].queryset = TrainingInstance.objects.filter(training__year ="current")
```

Comment: Looks good to me, well done